# Is AMD OpenCL SDK portable?

Tags: opencl, gpu, amd-processor

I was looking around for a download for the OpenCL API when I discovered that it was platform specific and depended on your graphics card in which I download the SDK. I gave it some thought and if the SDK depends on your graphics card would it make scents to think that it would require those same dependencies at runtime? In short, will a program made with the AMD SDK still run on a computer with a NVIDEA graphics card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure what gave you the impression that OpenCL applications developed with one vendor's SDK are not portable - they absolutely are.

In fact, you don't even need an SDK from any particular vendor to develop OpenCL applications. You can download the header files and source code for the OpenCL ICD loader (the library you should link against) from the [Khronos OpenCL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/). The headers and library that come with any of the OpenCL SDKs that you download should be exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you. The reason thant I was confused about portability should be odvious...

Comment: In fact, thats how I do it. Plus using LoadLibrary(), in case CL is not in the system. It works like a charm for all the platforms.